# How can I insert-select a sequence starting from a variable?

Tags: sql-server, sequence

There was a question here on SO that was since then removed. But while I was researching for ways to solve it, I was writing a script that avoids the use of an identity column and uses a sequence itself:

```
create table table1(Id int primary key, group_id int, Name varchar(64))
insert into table1(Id, group_id, Name) values (1, 1, 'a'), (2, 1, 'b'), (4, 1, 'c'), (8, 1, 'd')
declare @MaxId as int
select @MaxId = max(Id) + 1 from table1
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = N'CREATE SEQUENCE MySequence  AS INTEGER START WITH ' + cast(@maxId as varchar(10))
exec(@sql)
insert into table1(id, group_id, Name)
select next value for MySequence, 2, Name
from table1
where group_id = 1;
```

This actually works, that is, it successfully inserts four records with dynamically generated ids.

However, the the part of

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = N'CREATE SEQUENCE MySequence  AS INTEGER START WITH ' + cast(@maxId as varchar(10))
exec(@sql)
```

is very much counter-intuitive and hacky in my opinion.

**Question**: Is there a way to define a sequence that starts from a variable's value without generating a text and execute it?

Comment: A fiddle for the experiment can be found at See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a2b03/1

Comment: The [CREATE SEQUENCE syntax documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax) shows a constant is required so you cannot specify a variable in the DDL statement.

Comment: @DanGuzman bad news. Unfortunately a "no, we can't" is also a possible answer. You refer to the `[ START WITH <constant> ]` part. You may answer this question with the link and quote, it will be helpful for future visitors.

Comment: Why don;t you use an `IDENTITY` column?

Comment: @Charlieface yes, that's the solution. But the question I have seen excluded that possibility, so I wondered whether it is possible with sequences without blatant hacks. It is not for real-world use, but a technical curiosity. Dan Guzman has shown exact proof that it is not possible in a not hacky way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CREATE SEQUENCE syntax documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax) shows a constant is required so you cannot specify a variable in the DDL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, creating a single-use dynamic sequence is a hack.

Instead use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), something like

```
use tempdb
drop table if exists table1
go
create table table1(id int, group_id int, name varchar(200))

insert into table1(id,group_id,name) values (1,1,'a')
insert into table1(id,group_id,name) values (2,1,'a')

declare @maxValue int = (select max(id) from table1)

insert into table1(id, group_id, Name)
select @maxValue + row_number() over (order by Id), 2, Name
from table1
where group_id = 1;


select * from table1
```

Comment: I'm aware of the `row_numer` solution, I was specifically interested whether it is possible with a sequence. It was not for my own use, I prefer identity columns, but a question arised here on SO, that was deleted since then and I wanted to answer it, yet, it turned out that doing it with sequence is an extremely ugly hack. I was wondering whether my conclusion for sequences was accurate and, as Dan Guzman pointed out in his answer, it was.